# MariaDB , Upgrade Version 10.5 , On Bulleyes

Tags: mariadb, debian, raspbian

hope u can help me out.

I try to upgrade my MariaDB-Server on Raspberry Pi 4 , with Debian 11 - Bulleyes.

Anyone can help me out to get the rigth settings to get my MariaDB 10.6+?
Thanks & have a nice Day!

Just edit the /etc/apt/sources to get the version of mariadb (10.6+).

Error :

N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-armhf/Packages' as repository 'https://mirror.creoline.net/mariadb/repo/10.10/debian bullseye InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'armhf'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MariaDB upstream doesn't release armhf packages as its not tested on this hardware. This is why it isn't in the MariaDB repo mirror you have used.

Debian tests part of a test suite and considers that good enough. Glad its working for you.

Debian 11 (Bullseye) only has [MariaDB-10.5](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/mariadb-server), while Debian 12 (Bookworm) has the [MariaDB-10.11](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/mariadb-server) version you are after.

So your options are:

- Upgrade to Bookworm
- Upgrade hardware to an Arm v8 (aarch64)
- [Build your own package from source](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/building-mariadb-on-debian/)